I wanted to write logs for the garry's mod server, but I have a problem
I have written logs for the server Garry's mod but I do not display information in the parameters "Damage" and "Connect" anyone can say what is wrong with the script?
I would like to add more logs of profession change how can it be done?
local logs = {
    kill = {},
    damage = {},
    changename = {},
    connect = {},
    disconnect = {},
    Kd = nil
}

-- Entity killed logging
gameevent.Listen("entity_killed")
hook.Add("entity_killed", "", function(data)
    if not logsEnabled then return end

    local victim = "unknown"
    local attacker = "map"
    local weapon = "Unknown gun"
    
    for _, ply in pairs(player.GetAll()) do
        if ply:EntIndex() == data.entindex_killed then
            victim = ply:Nick()
        end
        if ply:EntIndex() == data.entindex_attacker then
            attacker = ply:Nick()
            local weaponEntity = ply:GetActiveWeapon()
            if IsValid(weaponEntity) then
                weapon = weaponEntity:GetPrintName()
            end
        end
    end

    table.insert(logs.kill, "[" .. os.date("%H:%M:%S") .. "] " .. attacker .. " killed player " .. victim .. " weapon " .. weapon)
end)

-- Entity damage logging
hook.Add("EntityTakeDamage", "", function(target, dmginfo)
    if not logsEnabled then return end
    if not target:IsPlayer() then return end

    local attacker = dmginfo:GetAttacker()
    local attackerName = "Unknown"
    local weapon = "Unknown gun"
    
    if attacker:IsPlayer() then
        attackerName = attacker:Nick()
        local weaponEntity = attacker:GetActiveWeapon()
        if IsValid(weaponEntity) then
            weapon = weaponEntity:GetPrintName()
        end
    end

    table.insert(logs.damage, "[" .. os.date("%H:%M:%S") .. "] " .. attackerName .. " did damage to a player " .. target:Nick() .. " на " .. dmginfo:GetDamage() .. " HP" .. " weapon " .. weapon)
end)

-- Chat name change and connect/disconnect logging
hook.Add("ChatText", "", function(index, name, text, type)
    if not logsEnabled then return end
    if type == "namechange" then
        table.insert(logs.changename, "[" .. os.date("%m/%d/%Y-%H:%M:%S") .. "] " .. name)
    elseif type == "joinleave" then
        local nickname, steamID = text:match("([^#]+)#([^%(]+)%(%d+:.-%)(.-)joined")
        if nickname and steamID then
            table.insert(logs.connect, "[" .. os.date("%H:%M:%S") .. "] " .. nickname .. " (" .. steamID .. ") connected.")
        end
    end
end)

-- Player disconnect logging
gameevent.Listen("player_disconnect")
hook.Add("player_disconnect", "", function(data)
    if not logsEnabled then return end
    table.insert(logs.disconnect, "[" .. os.date("%H:%M:%S") .. "] " .. data.name .. " (" .. data.networkid .. "). " .. data.reason)
end)

-- Create fonts
surface.CreateFont("LogFont", { font = "Arial", size = 22, weight = 1000 })
surface.CreateFont("TitleFont", { font = "Amb", size = 20 })

local function createLogWindow()
    local frame = vgui.Create("DFrame")
    frame:SetSize(670, 370)
    frame:Center()
    frame:SetTitle("")
    frame:ShowCloseButton(false)
    frame:SetRenderInScreenshots(false)
    frame:MakePopup()

    function frame:Paint()
        local blur = Material("pp/blurscreen")
        local x, y = self:LocalToScreen(0, 0)
        local screenW, screenH = ScrW(), ScrH()
        surface.SetDrawColor(255, 255, 255)
        surface.SetMaterial(blur)
        for i = 1, 3 do
            blur:SetFloat("$blur", i / 3 * 6)
            blur:Recompute()
            render.UpdateScreenEffectTexture()
            surface.DrawTexturedRect(-x, -y, screenW, screenH)
        end
        draw.RoundedBox(4, 0, 0, self:GetWide(), self:GetTall(), Color(0, 0, 0, 170))
        draw.SimpleText("ClientSide Logs", "TitleFont", 5, 3, Color(255, 255, 255, 255), 0, 0)
        surface.SetDrawColor(Color(0, 0, 0, 255))
        surface.DrawOutlinedRect(0, 0, self:GetWide(), self:GetTall())
        surface.DrawOutlinedRect(0, 0, 619, 26)
        surface.DrawOutlinedRect(0, 25, self:GetWide(), self:GetTall() - 25)
        surface.SetDrawColor(Color(0, 0, 0, 255))
        surface.DrawOutlinedRect(0, 25, 170, 610)
    end

    local closeButton = vgui.Create("DButton", frame)
    closeButton:SetTextColor(Color(150, 150, 150))
    closeButton:SetText("X")
    closeButton:SetFont("LogFont")
    closeButton:SetPos(619, 1)
    closeButton:SetSize(50, 24)
    closeButton.DoClick = function()
        frame:SizeTo(0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0.2)
        timer.Simple(0.3, function()
            frame:SetVisible(false)
        end)
    end
    closeButton.Paint = function(self, w, h)
        surface.SetDrawColor(Color(0, 0, 0, 255))
        surface.DrawOutlinedRect(0, 0, w, h)
        draw.RoundedBox(0, 0, 0, w, h, Color(139, 0, 0, 255))
    end
    closeButton.OnCursorEntered = function()
        surface.PlaySound("garrysmod/ui_hover.wav")
        closeButton.Paint = function(self, w, h)
            draw.RoundedBox(0, 0, 0, w, h, Color(220, 20, 60, 255))
        end
    end
    closeButton.OnCursorExited = function()
        closeButton.Paint = function(self, w, h)
            draw.RoundedBox(0, 0, 0, w, h, Color(139, 0, 0, 255))
        end
    end

    local searchBox = vgui.Create("DTextEntry", frame)
    searchBox:SetPos(410, 1)
    searchBox:SetSize(200, 24)
    searchBox:SetPlaceholderText("Search logs...")

    local function updateLogs(logTable)
        if IsValid(logs.Kd) then logs.Kd:Remove() end
        logs.Kd = vgui.Create("RichText", frame)
        logs.Kd:SetPos(174, 30)
        logs.Kd:SetSize(491, 335)
        logs.Kd:SetFontInternal("LogFont")
        logs.Kd.Paint = function(self, w, h)
            self:SetBGColor(Color(0, 0, 0, 120))
            surface.SetDrawColor(Color(0, 0, 0, 255))
            surface.DrawOutlinedRect(0, 0, w, h)
        end
        logs.Kd:InsertColorChange(255, 255, 255, 255)
        local searchQuery = searchBox:GetValue():lower()
        for _, log in pairs(logTable) do
            if searchQuery == "" or string.find(log:lower(), searchQuery) then
                logs.Kd:AppendText(log .. "\n")
            end
        end
    end

    searchBox.OnChange = function()
        if IsValid(logs.Kd) and IsValid(logs.Kd.activeButton) then
            logs.Kd.activeButton.DoClick()
        end
    end

    local buttonYPos = 30
    local function createLogButton(text, logTable)
        local button = vgui.Create("DButton", frame)
        button:SetPos(5, buttonYPos)
        button:SetSize(160, 30)
        button:SetText(text)
        button:SetFont("LogFont")
        button:SetTextColor(Color(255, 255, 255, 255))
        button.DoClick = function()
            if IsValid(logs.Kd) then
                logs.Kd.activeButton = button
                updateLogs(logTable)
            end
        end
        button.OnCursorEntered = function()
            surface.PlaySound("garrysmod/ui_hover.wav")
        end
        function button:Paint(w, h)
            draw.RoundedBox(0, 0, 0, w, h, Color(0, 0, 0, 120))
            surface.SetDrawColor(Color(0, 0, 0, 255))
            surface.DrawOutlinedRect(0, 0, w, h)
        end
        buttonYPos = buttonYPos + 35
    end

    createLogButton("Kill", logs.kill)
    createLogButton("Damage", logs.damage)
    createLogButton("Connect", logs.connect)
    createLogButton("Disconnect", logs.disconnect)

    return frame
end

hook.Add("Think", "", function()
    if input.IsKeyDown(KEY_END) and not Q then
        if v then
            v:Close()
            v = nil
        else
            v = createLogWindow()
        end
    end
    Q = input.IsKeyDown(KEY_END)
end)

concommand.Add("toggle_logs", function()
    logsEnabled = not logsEnabled
    print("Logging is now " .. (logsEnabled and "enabled" or "disabled"))
end)

concommand.Add("logs_stop", function()
    logsEnabled = false
    print("Logging has stopped.")
end)

To get the information about the connected player I wanted to get it from the chat, but it didn't work.

this is not a debugging service, narrow down your problem. There is no need to bother us with > 200 lines of code.

Your damage logs are probably missing because this code is meant to run on the client, but "EntityTakeDamage" is a serverside event- https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/GM:EntityTakeDamage .
As for connection logs, it would be simpler to use the player connect event- https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/gameevent/player_connect
